# Special characters not getting write to csv file

Tags: java, spring, csv, export-to-csv

I am using spring boot application and writing to csv file. Here is controller method

```
 @PostMapping(value = "/audit/keys",  produces = "text/csv", consumes = "multipart/form-data")
 public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getEmployeeReport(
        @RequestPart(value="file") MultipartFile multiPartFile,
        HttpServletResponse response) {
    try {
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=EmployeeRecord.csv");
        service.getEmployeeRecords(multiPartFile, response);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("File can not b read", e);
    }
    return null;
}
```

here is my service method

```
  public void getEmployeeRecords(MultipartFile multiPartFile,
        HttpServletResponse response){


// csv generator 
    CsvGenerator csvGenerator = CSV_FACTORY.createGenerator(response.getOutputStream());
    CsvMapper mapper = new CsvMapper();
    mapper.configure(JsonGenerator.Feature.IGNORE_UNKNOWN, true);
    mapper.configure(CsvGenerator.Feature.ALWAYS_QUOTE_STRINGS, true);
    mapper.enable(CsvGenerator.Feature.STRICT_CHECK_FOR_QUOTING);

   csvGenerator.writeObject(dao.fetchEmpRecords());
   
   csvGenerator.flush();
   csvGenerator.close();

}
```

And my database contains following records

```
  empId    empName             empAddress
  123    Roy John          Street 2 Nawada
  340    Roy Jennings      Street # 2 contact $$$
```

Since 2nd record contains `# $ etc` its not getting written in `Csv` however i can see both the records on the UI on response/preview tab.However `EmployeeRecord.csv`  contains only one record.tried with `produces = "text/csv; charset=UTF-8"` but it didn't worked for me , i am using Apace common library and would like to use `IOUtils` but no luck so far :(

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with the http transfer. It rather looks like Jackson issue.

Comment: Why is your controller method’s signature `ResponseEntity<byte[]>` when you only ever return `null`? Why do you think this question has anhything at all to do with Spring Boot? The `getEmployeeRecords()` you show is not the one that is called in the controller. Do you want to _write_ data (using POST) or _return_ data (you call `fetch` on the DAO)?

Answer (score 0):

```
csvGenerator.writeObject(dao.fetchEmpRecords());
```

This method for writing one given Java object (POJO).
Try call it for each record in cycle.